# Relative URLs not being changed correctly by Django compressor

Tags: django, django-compressor

For exmaple, in my SCSS file,

```
url('../../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot');
```

turns into

```
url('https://fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot');
```

which obviously does not work.

I have in my settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'digital_time_capsules'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE
COMPRESS_URL = "https://digital_time_capsules.s3.amazonaws.com/"
STATIC_URL = COMPRESS_URL
```

I tried several times to run compress, and restart the server, and whatnot. It worked once, yesterday, and I got the full path to S3. But now it doesn't, and my custom resources don't load.

Bootstrap's URLs seem to always work, though. It did successfully generate

```
image:url('https://digital_time_capsules.s3.amazonaws.com/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the relative path of the `fonts` folder is 1 level higher. So try:

`url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot');`